# Delphi 'Cannot resolve unit name 'FireDac.phys.mysql'

Tags: android, mysql, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to build my project to an android application within Delphi Berlin 10.1. The only thing is that when I change my target platform to Android it 'Cannot resolve unit name 'FireDac.phys.mysql'.

While everything is ok and I can build in the target platform 32-bit windows.

Is there a special path location for android I have to specify? or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

Android has built in support only for SQL Lite database [Android Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Unit you are linking to contains MySQL Server support that is not available on Android.

On Android side you can use [FireDAC.Phys.SQLite](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Phys.SQLite)

Comment: So it isn't possible to extract data from a MySql database directly on a Android app, so that's why a middle tier (Datasnap) needs to be used. I really thought it could.

Comment: Now you understand everything! :-)